# Regex to match pattern consisting of several groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have the  following regular expression, but it only matches the last occurrence of the pattern found. The regular expression is designed to match the following pattern:

A single digit followed by a \

A word followed by \

Another word followed by \

The forth group can either be a single word followed by a \ or 2 or 3 words followed by \

The fifth group must be a floating point number in the format 00.00

The regular expression is:

```
([0-9])\\(\w+)\\(\w+)\\((\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)|\w+\s\w+|\w+)\\([+-]?\d*\.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])\\
```

The string being match is:

```
2\James\Brown\Football Club Mu\15.45\1\Jessie\Ellis\Football Club Performance\15.48\4\Dane\Brown\FC Football \15.52\5\Richardo\Flemmings\Football Club Striders\15.53\7\Lawrence\Brown\Football Club Testing\15.53\8\Jermy\Black\Football Club Ch\15.34\\
```

The match of the last record is only detected if the regex expression does not terminate with \\ and the string that is to be matched against the regular expression does not terminate with "\\".

Note, the string that is to be compared to the regular expression always terminates with a "\\".

Comment: I tried to check your regex pattern with the expression,but it isn't working. Can you check its syntax at: https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can check the working regular expression at: https://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you provided doesn't appear to work at all. I can't make out what you're trying to do with that, especially the '+' and '-' characters. To perfectly match your definition, I've got this:

```
([0-9])\\\w+\\\w+\\(\w+( \w+)?( \w+)?)\\[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]
```

Although your examples don't quite match your definition, as they have a trailing '\', and the third example has a trailing space in the fourth group. Assuming those examples are valid, I've modified it to this:

```
([0-9])\\\w+\\\w+\\(\w+( \w+)?( \w+)?) ?\\[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\\
```

Comment: I just tested this solution, it matches the string that is it compared against. What modification will need to made to check for a float which has the following pattern 0.00. If I modify the pattern to 0.00 for the float then there is not match for that string.

Comment: The floating regex: `[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?`

Comment: I modified the check for the float to (\d+\.\d+) to address the question that I asked.

Comment: The regular expression does not matches the search for this \4\Dane\Brown\ Football \15.52

Comment: The regular expression does not matches the search for this 4 Dane Brown FC Football 15.52

Comment: @AndreReid That input doesn't match your given specification. It has a leading '/' and leading and trailing spaces in the fourth group. Also, it's not clear if a trailing '/' is valid given your specification and examples. I think you need to decide exactly what is and isn't valid before I can help you any further

Comment: I just realized and made the necessary changes thanks